# 3D Barriers, ArcGIS Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-10.1, routing, 3d, network-analyst

I am trying to implement 3D barriers from a feature class into a network using a model, but I can't seem to get the resulting barrier to appear on the proper three dimensional plane. The feature class that the barrier is generated from a 3D feature, and displays properly in ArcScene. Yet when I run my model, the barrier that appears in the route layer doesn't retain the 3D information. I need to have the 3D information, as I don't want to apply the barrier to all features just to the features on that specific plane.

I have the barriers set up via a second "Add Location" tool, as a polygon barrier after the Add Location tool that generates the stops. Is there something that I need to set in the tool itself to retain the Z information from the feature class? I do not have "Use Network Location Fields instead of Geometry" selected.

Below a picture of the problem. The green is the feature class, red is the barrier that is created after running the model.

I should also add that I do not need the barrier to be extruded, or represent a three dimensional box or object, just that it needs to have the correct elevation.

I am using ArcGIS 10.1, with the Network Analyst extension, model creating the 3D routes via Model Builder.

Thanks,

eric

[image: Barrier Problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that barriers do not retain 3D information when processed, and the barrier will apply to all features regardless of z value. Read this thread to gain more information: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/80757-3D-Barriers